# How to allow unauthenticated guest to access inbound flow (Lightning Scheduler)

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-scheduler

I have spent the last two weeks with Salesforce Support to no avail. We activated Lightning Scheduler and would like to use the feature allowing external users to access our inbound scheduling flow from our website. I have the flow on a community website for testing and when I access it as a guest, there is a generic error where the flow should be. I'm assuming a permissions issue, but I have custom sharing rules set on the objects required. Has anyone run in to this problem before or have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Set the flow running mode to use sharing settings. On the flow click the gear icon to locate this.